# ArcMap 10.8 crashes after using tools from Toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.8

Total beginner here.
Everytime I use any tool from Toolbox (Merge, Clip, Buffer etc.) ArcMap happens to crash. I work with version 10.8.
As you might guess from my name, my language uses diacritics - I made sure that the all of the folders chosen during the installation process didn't include any in their names, however, I ended up with this destination for my .mxt template...

Could that be the source of the problem?

[image]

Comment: Is this a brand new install, or did you upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: New install....

Comment: More questions - you say when using tools it crashes. Does it crash when you OPEN a tool, or when you push RUN on a tool?  Do you have Background Processing on or off? Does it crash and disappear or crash and popup a dialog saying "do you want to send in a crash report"?

Comment: ArcMap crashes when I run the tool. After crashing everything completely disappears, there is no popup dialog or error message

Comment: Are you the administrator of the computer or is it an University computer you are using?

Comment: It's on my own PC